# LINQ C# Except items from one list

Tags: c#, linq

I have Posts table:

```
Id  ReplyId
1   null
2   1
3   null
4   3
5   null
```

`posts` contains all of these items.
I want to except posts where Id = ReplyId, so in result I want to get posts with Ids 2,4,5.

In other words, we can see ReplyId = 1 then we need to remove from list Post with Id = 1. Also ReplyId = 3 then remove from list Post with Id = 3.

How can I implement that?

Comment: can you post the sample code that you have tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
posts.Where(x => !posts.Any(y => y.ReplyId == x.Id))
```

test:

```
void Main()
{
    var posts = new[] {
        new Post { Id = 1, ReplyId = null},
        new Post { Id = 2, ReplyId = 1},
        new Post { Id =3,  ReplyId = null},
        new Post { Id = 4, ReplyId = 3},
        new Post { Id = 5, ReplyId = null},
    };


    var endItems = posts.Where(x => !posts.Any(y => y.ReplyId == x.Id));
    foreach (var element in endItems)
        Console.WriteLine(element.Id);
}

class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? ReplyId { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
var posts = new[]
{
    new { Id = 1, ReplyId = (int?)null, },
    new { Id = 2, ReplyId = (int?)1, },
    new { Id = 3, ReplyId = (int?)null, },
    new { Id = 4, ReplyId = (int?)3, },
    new { Id = 5, ReplyId = (int?)null, },
};

var query =
    from p in posts
    join p2 in posts on p.Id equals p2.ReplyId into g
    where !g.Any()
    select p;
```

I get:

[image: query]

Comment: posts is IQueryable, IsEmpty() need to replace with something other

Comment: @A.Gladkiy -Done.